# Posting comments on LQP reviews

Tags: discussion, comments, review, low-quality-posts

I have just encountered a review item on which I was unsure.

https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/838262

It is from SuperUser's Low Quality Posts queue, a self-answer:

> To answer my own question, I was able to use VLOOKUP to condition on the results from the relevant column.

I did not know what to do, it does bring some answer elements but at the same time it does not explain how to solve the problem.

- It did not "Look OK", so in my mind this option was out
- I could not "Edit" this answer, since I did not know how the author solved the problem
- I didn't want to recommend deleting it, to give time to the user to edit their answer themselves

In the end, since it is a self-answer, I posted a comment asking the user to explain their solution in more details, and skipped the review.

Was there a better course of action, that I should have taken? Did what I do go against the purpose of LQP review queue?

Comment: As this question is about a specific site, you should post it on [Meta superuser](https://meta.superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: I thought it was more about the Low Quality review queue in general, but in fact I do not know if this queue is specific to SuperUser. This is why I posted it here. If I have confirmation that it's SU-specific, I will gladly remove this question and ask it on Meta-SU instead.

Comment: You'll find that different sites have different standards for what they consider low quality posts. It's better to ask a question like this on the child site's meta. On some sites a single sentence answer may suffice in some situations, but then on other sites a one sentence answer is almost never appropriate. Etc, etc..

Comment: Actually as a broader, global issue they affects core mechanics of the network, I think MSE is appropriate

Comment: OK I will defer to the wise dog.

Comment: @n8te In some culture (e.g. Chinese), calling someone a dog (wise or not) is an insulting remark.

Comment: His profile pic is a dog.

Comment: What you did sounds fine to me. That's why the skip button is there.

Comment: @scaaahu - Everyone who knows Journeyman, knows he is our resident Schnauzer, calling him a man would be insulting to him.

Comment: You could always return to it later and if the OP has not edited it then flag it for moderator attention and explain why you did what you did and ask them to delete it if they see fit.